# Updating an instance variable for an object from another class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

There are two `UIViewController` classes. One of them is a `UITableViewController` which reloads its data when `needUpdating` variable is true.
This variable should be updated in another class.

I make an instance from it and change this variable but I think that as this instance is not the one that is running nothing changes, so `needUpdating` is not updated.

```
class A: UITableViewController{
    var needUpdating: Bool = false
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       ...
       if needUpdating {
           tableView.reloadData()
       }
    }
}
class B: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       ...
       var a = A()
       if ... {
           a.needUpdating = true
       }
    }
}
```

---

These two `UIViewController` are unrelated. They are not connected using `segue`

Comment: you can use protocols.
write a protocol and self the instance when navigating, and call it with the value, so you can update the variable in the first class.
i can write a sample code, if you want.

Comment: @Mina Thanks. if you don't mind please send your sample code.

Comment: @FattanehTalebi Check out the answer below.

Comment: Use Delegate pattern (Protocol) to pass data between controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first viewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerSecondDelegate {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Next" {
        let vc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerSecond
        vc?.delegate = self
     }
   }
   func secondDelegate(_ value: Bool) {
      print("delegate") //needUpdating = value
    }
 }
```

and this is the secondViewController:

```
protocol ViewControllerSecondDelegate {
    func secondDelegate(_ value: Bool)
}

class ViewControllerSecond: UIViewController {
   weak var delegate: ViewControllerSecondDelegate?

   override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
       delegate?.secondDelegate(true) //call this wherever you need it.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how should I create segue called Next. I tried control dragging from B view controller to A view controller and some segues like show and ... were shown but I don't want to show controller to A . I just want to set its variable.

Comment: you have to `self ` the ViewControllerSecondDelegate. you can do it wherever you have the instance of your desireController. i  `vc?.delegate = self` it in `prepare` because that's where i have the instance of my destination controller.

Answer (score 1):

**Every object has its own properties so here You are creating a new one instance:**

```
class B: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       var a = A()
       if ... {
           a.needUpdating = true
       }
    }
}

var a = A()
```

You have to pass your old instance **do not create new instance** `var a = A()`

You can pass you old instance something like this:

```
class A: UITableViewController{
    var needUpdating: Bool = false
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       ...
       if needUpdating {
           tableView.reloadData()
       }
    }
    //WHEN YOU PUSHED TO B ASSIGN THE CLASS A INSTANCE IN B CLASSS
    func pushToB {
         //PUSH STUFF
        var b = B()
        b.a = self

    }
}
class B: UIViewController {
    var a:A?
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { 
       if ... {
           a?.needUpdating = true
       }
    }
}
```

Passed the instance like this:

```
let instance = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("B")as! B
instance.a = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(instance, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks. where should I call pushToB?

Comment: @FattanehTalebi when you are push your viewcontroller its gives you the instance then called with viewcontroller instance.

Comment: if you are not understand then provide the full code

Answer (score 0):

In your Appdelegate Class make a variable of UITableViewController

```
'var tableViewController: A?'
```

In your Class A make this Changes

'

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    class A: UITableViewController{
        var needUpdating: Bool = false
        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
           ...
            appDelegate.tableViewController = self
           if needUpdating {
               tableView.reloadData()
           }
        }
    }'
```

In Your Class B use AppDelegate variable reference instead of creating new instance

```
'class B: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       ...
       var a = appDelegate.tableViewController
       if ... {
           a.needUpdating = true
       }
    }
}'
```

Comment: You haven't  kept the instance in your app delegate that is bad programming because ARC will never remove the instance throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use any type of `segue` according to your requirement. I have used `Present Modally` `segue` to present controller `B`

```
class A: UITableViewController
{
    var needUpdating: Bool = false
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //...
        if needUpdating
        {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "BController"
        {
            let controller = segue.destination as! B
            controller.a = self
        }
    }
}
class B: UIViewController
{
    var a = A()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //...
        if ...
        {
            a.needUpdating = true
        }
    }
}
```

Also you need to add `UITableViewDataSource` methods to make it work.